# Ender 3 with Trianglelab matrix extruder

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, direct-drive

I ordered a matrix direct drive extruder from Trianglelab and printed two mounts for it.

The mounts I have printed are found [here](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4686413).

I have only printed the first and second part from the referenced link above.

Should these be enough to get the extruder mounted and start testing with it?

I have a hard time figuring out which way the extruder should be connected with these mounts.

Comment: The mount is for a LulzBot TAZ 5 printer, not an Ender 3. It would be an addition to the question if you expressed why you are using the LulzBot TAZ 5 mount on the Ender 3 to prevent answers that you are using the incorrect printer part. Unless that is actually the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the question is updated why a LulzBot TAZ printer part is used on the Ender 3, it is unclear why you would want to use the parts from the [linked Thingiverse source](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4686413); quote:

> These are the parts needed to mount a Trianglelab Matrix extruder to a Taz 5 and Workhorse.

The LulzBot concept uses the linear rods concept (Prusa i3 style) for the X-axis while the Ender 3 uses a wheel based carriage running on a 2020 aluminium extrusion profile. For comparison, see the image below to show the differences between the Ender 3 and the TAZ:

[image]

A specific mount for the Ender 3 is found [here](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4849159).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't find the correct one.